# Cant able to call SendCodeRequestAsync method in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, telegram

I am stuck at one point while using TLSharp library for using Telegram API in .Net. Below is my code that i am trying to send a code request using `client.SendCodeRequestAsync() method`

```
            client = new TelegramClient(238363, "9f176b5a6eec1efc8ff58bbc7766e266");
            await client.ConnectAsync();
            var hash = await client.SendCodeRequestAsync("91XXXXXXXXXX");
            if (hash != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(hash);
            }`
```

the above code is giving me **An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used [2001:b28:f23f:f005::a]:443** error. Don't know what is wrong. I googled out a lot and tried alot but still the problem remains the same.So please anyone who can help me out.

Comment: if you have `session` file, remove it and test agian

Comment: can you help me where i can find the session file in my project ?. i am new in WPF and TLSharp

Comment: When user is authenticated, TLSharp creates special file called `session.dat`. In this file TLSharp store all information needed for user session. So you need to authenticate user every time the session.dat file is corrupted or removed.

Comment: Sorry but you are saying this for browser, and my project is windows based project and no session.dat file is created in the project at all.

Comment: do you use https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp  ??

Comment: if you use `TLSharp` , This document describes `session` https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp  and https://www.sochix.ru/how-to-send-messages-to-telegram-from-c/

Comment: if you use `TLSharp` , This document describes `session` https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp  and https://www.sochix.ru/how-to-send-messages-to-telegram-from-c/

Comment: yes exactly...!!! i am using this only in WPF

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173597/discussion-between-anmol-rathod-and-alihossein-shahabi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally resolved this problem. The main reason behind this problem was the IP address version were not matching. So, as per [This Refrence](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp/issues/773)  I found `var dc = dcOptions.First(d => d.Id == dcId);` and replaced it with `var dc = dcOptions.First(d => d.Id == dcId && !d.Ipv6);` this line  in TelegramClient.cs file and it worked like charm..

Answer (score 4):

IPv6 is not supported,
So : `new TelegramClient(api_id, api_hash, dcIpVersion: DataCenterIPVersion.OnlyIPv4);`
DataCenterIPVersion enum => set OnlyIPv4 as above.